# How to read info about installed programs from hard drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-registry

I need to move a software from a laptop that I have not used in 3 years to my new laptop.  Unfortunately I no longer have the AC adapter for the old laptop, and the battery is dead since I have not used it for so long.  I only need a code which I believe should be in the registry.  If possible I would like to view a list of all installed programs on my old machine, but this is not as crucial for me.

The obvious solution is to buy an AC adapter and power up the machine.  I would prefer to avoid this as the computer and the program info is not worth the cost of the adapter to me.  I can take out the external hard drive and read it from another machine.  Is there a way to read the registry/get info about installed programs using another computer with the old laptop's hard drive connected as an external drive?

The old laptop has Windows XP installed and I am now working from a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: assuming you're doing this because of trying to preserve personal data not in the registry: If that piece of software doesn't store any important personal information in the registry. I would do a fresh install of the software, then grab the old data, and overwrite it with the new installation files.

Comment: @Sickest, not sure exactly what you mean.  I can read the old hard drive so I can get the data files.  What I want is to see what programs were installed before and for one software specifically, I want a license number which I think is in the registry.

Comment: oh ok, my suggest was in the situation opposite of that, if you want to see a list of programs installed, registry is not the place to look, because it will have every piece of software you ever install, so old and current. Just look in your program files for the list. As far as the license number, I can't help you there. Don't think it's possible unless you backed up your registry ahead of time.

Comment: @Sickest, I see your point about the list of installed programs, that makes sense.  I'll just look at the program files list.  As for the license number, that's what I was afraid of.

Comment: The license number/whatever can probably be recovered, but it might not work on the new computer if it's tied to the old hardware. What's the program name/version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to check out this solution i found: [Source](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/212597/edit-registry-of-a-slave-hard-drive/)

A guide to edit the registry of a slaved Hard Drive on a XP System.

NOTE 1 : to edit the system hive the regedit will ask you for the key name; search it from the
       following site
       URL : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724877(VS.85).aspx

NOTE 2 : The table that shows the Registry Hive and the supporting Files is described in the
following line.
Registry Hive : The Hive you want to edit
Supporting Files : Is the Key Name that regedit will ask for the hive you wish to edit.

Let's Begin,

Go to 
Start > run > type regedit > click on machine

File > Load Hive
Browse to the slaved Hard Drive; Windows > System 32 > Config > choose the hive you want to edit and 
search the key name from the above site.

You have full control of the registry of the Hard drive that is slaved connected.
DO IT AT YOUR OWN RISKS!

`If you want to see a list of programs installed, registry is not the place to look, because it will have every piece of software you ever install, so old and current. Just look in your program files for the list.`